# Why does the Rabbi face the congregation during prayer?

Tags: rabbis, synagogue

In nearly every shul I've been in the Rav of the shul sits up near the aron kodesh and faces towards the congregation instead of facing east. I assume this is in keeping with halacha (as mentioned in an answer) but I would like to understand what purpose (if any) this serves conceptually?

Comment: re edit: see [this](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/703/759) and I note that the last paragraph [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1231/759) applies

Comment: @DoubleAA are you saying the question is now vague?

Comment: I'm saying it was vague and your clarification invalidated an existing answer.

Comment: Opposite question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95197/170

Comment: Abraham Ben haRambam Actually banned this practice

Comment: In German kehillos, the custom is that the rov's seat is beside, rather than on, the duchan and that he faces the same direction as the kohol, rather than towards them

Comment: @TheKugelMan actually, successfully banned it? Or just decried it and things continued as usual? (I guess we should ask his descendant, R. Moshe Maimon of Monsey!)

Comment: Well In his particular congregation it was probably up to him unless there was a bigger big shot in his shul. 
U should he’s a great guy. He’ll probably know

Answer (score 9):

[Tosefta Megila 3:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47525&st=&pgnum=298) says that the elders would sit facing the congregation. As per DoubleAA's comment this is codified in [Orach Chaim 150:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A0_%D7%94). The question is really on the  Rabbis that do  not do so.

[Kav Chaim 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1963&st=&pgnum=18) says the reason the front row faces the congregation is since the Bima is in the center of the Synagogue and that is where the Torah is read, that way there is a remembrance of Har Sinai, where all were facing the mountain.

Comment: @GershonGold, מפני כבוד הציבור http://www.tshuvos.com/showSefer.asp?sefer=Beis_Shearim_Orach_Chaim&min=1&max=318&seperator=no&numCode=55

Comment: Just asked a [related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95197/159)

Comment: What's interesting is that they focus on the shulchan rather than the *teiva* which is usually in the front, but it can be in the middle. Point is that the majority of the time in shul is tefillah rather than Torah reading so most of the activity tends to be in the front. Perhaps, taht should be considered the main focus.

Answer (score 3):

I heard once from [Rabbi Yisroel Miller](http://www.hojmi.org/rabbi.php) that the reason for this is to instill fear in the tzibur during davening.

Answer (score 0):

Natan the Bavli describes the Yarchei Kallah in the Geonic period, there he describes the various religious leaders (head of the yeshiva, second tier heads of study groups etc.) who would sit opposite the students on the wall that the aron kodesh was placed. This seems to be part of the pomp and circumstance that was modeled after the staged processes and seating arrangements of the king's court.

Source: Mordechai Breuer, Ohalei Torah (The Yeshiva, Its Structure and History)

Comment: Where does Yehuda the Bavli describe this? Please include a source. The Yarchei Kallah are months of communal learning — does your source specify times of prayer?